# MySQL search within polygon

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding

I have a table in my database containing different Points of Interest with `Latitude` and `Longitude` for each POI.

I also have another table that has regions and their positions, every corner has Lat and Lng

```
2.33369:48.86395;2.31762:48.86329;2.29889:48.86092;2.29304:48.85443;2.28552:48.85353;2.29266:48.84569;2.30383:48.84732;2.31045:48.84532;2.31388:48.85148;2.32874:48.85779;2.33468:48.85905
```

this translates in Google Maps: image link in comments.

How can I search in my table and find only the points within those boundaries?

Searched all day for answers and can't figure out how to do it.
I cannot alter any of the tables but I can search in them.

Thank you.

Comment: Google Image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KFncY.png

Comment: I guess you will need the Spatial Extension for this :( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html

Comment: Here's a link to MySQL 5.6 which has more advanced spatial functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html

Comment: Since you probably don't have geospatial types in your table (POINT, POLYGON, etc), and can't modify it consider making a copy of the tables and converting them to use geospatial fields.